# Low performance on inserts with partitioned table in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, performance, database-partitioning

I have a partitioned table in oracle 12c with about 50 millions records. When i make a insert query against the db the response time is about 300 milliseconds, which is really slow compared to an equivalent PostgreSQL with the same data.

I tried to tune it with a lot of combinations of hints: pctfree, pctused values and so on. I don`t know what to do next, any ideas?

The query executed (using automated tests creating simultaneous sessions) is

```
INSERT INTO SLOW_PERF_TABLE (RTL_ID_SLOW_PERF_TABLE, ...) VALUES (SLOW_PERF_TABLE_seq.nextval, ...)
```

The partitioned table is creatd like this:

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------
> --  DDL for Table SLOW_PERF_TABLE
> --------------------------------------------------------
>
>   CREATE TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" 
>    (  "C_ID_SLOW_PERF_TABLE" NUMBER(19,0), 
>   "C_TX_CODE" NUMBER(19,0), 
>   "C_ENT_TX_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
>   "C_CATEGORY" NUMBER(10,0), 
>   "C_TYPE" NUMBER(10,0), 
>   "C_II" NUMBER(10,0), 
>   "C_EE" NUMBER(19,2), 
>   "C_DD_ID" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
>   "C_BB" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
>   "C_DESTINATION" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
>   "C_OR_POINT" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
>   "C_TX_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6), 
>   "C_EXEC_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6), 
>   "C_RESULT" NUMBER(10,0), 
>   "C_RESULT_MESSAGE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
>   "C_RESPONSE_MESSAGE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
>   "C_TOTAL_AA_VALUE" NUMBER(5,2), 
>   "C_TX_STATUS" NUMBER(5,0) DEFAULT 2, 
>   "C_LE_RELATED" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT '0', 
>   "C_DUPLICATED" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT '0', 
>   "C_BATCH_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
>   "C_GROUP_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
>   "C_ADDITIONAL_INFO" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
>    ) PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255  NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" 
>   PARTITION BY RANGE ("C_TX_TIMESTAMP") 
>  (PARTITION "C_BEFORE_2012"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-01-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_01"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-02-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_02"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-03-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_03"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-04-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_04"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-05-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_05"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-06-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_06"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-07-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_07"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-08-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_08"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-09-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_09"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-10-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_10"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-11-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_11"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2012-12-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2012_12"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-01-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_01"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-02-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_02"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-03-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_03"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-04-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_04"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-05-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_05"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-06-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_06"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-07-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_07"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-08-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_08"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-09-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_09"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-10-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_10"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-11-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_11"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2013-12-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2013_12"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-01-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_01"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-02-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_02"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-03-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_03"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-04-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_04"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-05-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_05"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-06-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_06"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-07-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_07"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-08-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_08"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-09-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_09"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-10-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_10"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-11-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_11"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2014-12-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2014_12"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2015-01-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2015_01"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2015-02-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2015_02"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2015-03-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2015_03"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2015-04-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2015_04"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2015-05-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 8388608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2015_05"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2015-06-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2019_09"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2019-10-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2019_10"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2019-11-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2019_11"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2019-12-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_2019_12"  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2020-01-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" , 
>  PARTITION "C_AFTER_2020"  VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
>   PCTFREE 40 PCTUSED 10 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
>  NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" ) ;
> --------------------------------------------------------
> --  DDL for Index C_ID_PK
> --------------------------------------------------------
>
>   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ANDRES"."C_ID_PK" ON "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" ("C_ID_SLOW_PERF_TABLE") 
>   PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
> --------------------------------------------------------
> --  DDL for Index C_TX_CODE_UNIQUE
> --------------------------------------------------------
>
>   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ANDRES"."C_TX_CODE_UNIQUE" ON "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" ("C_TX_CODE") 
>   PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
> --------------------------------------------------------
> --  DDL for Index C_TIMESTAMP_INDEX
> --------------------------------------------------------
>
>   CREATE INDEX "ANDRES"."C_TIMESTAMP_INDEX" ON "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" ("C_TX_TIMESTAMP" DESC) 
>   PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
>   ALTER INDEX "ANDRES"."C_TIMESTAMP_INDEX"  UNUSABLE;
> --------------------------------------------------------
> --  Constraints for Table SLOW_PERF_TABLE
> --------------------------------------------------------
>
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "C_TX_CODE_UNIQUE" UNIQUE ("C_TX_CODE")
>   USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "C_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("C_ID_SLOW_PERF_TABLE")
>   USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOLOGGING 
>   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
>   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
>   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
>   TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_RESULT" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_EXEC_TIMESTAMP" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_TX_TIMESTAMP" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_EE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_II" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_TYPE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_CATEGORY" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_ENT_TX_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_TX_CODE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
>   ALTER TABLE "ANDRES"."SLOW_PERF_TABLE" MODIFY ("C_ID_SLOW_PERF_TABLE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
> +
> ```

Comment: Table definitions, trace files, query plans, SQL statements, etc. would all be helpful.  Are you inserting 1 row or 1 million?  Using bind variables or literals?  Is there a query or are you inserting a set of values?  As it sits, no one can possibly do anything other than speculate wildly.

Comment: Or any materialised view with fast refresh against the table?

Comment: The insert is this:

INSERT INTO SLOW_PERF_TABLE 
(RTL_ID_SLOW_PERF_TABLE, ...) 
VALUES 
(SLOW_PERF_TABLE_seq.nextval, ...)

The response time is 370 milliseconds when i sent 10 simultaneous inserts, is postgress is 50 milliseconds

Comment: "10 simultaneous inserts" from different sessions?

Comment: yes, different sessions

Comment: If I had to guess I'd think about contention on the unique indexes, but you need to run a trace to find out.

Comment: Thank you, i will check.

Comment: also check initrans. where does the data come from? and why multiple session in parallel? If the data is just copied from an other database, use smarter loading instead of row by row.

Comment: did you ever figure out what happened?